# SQL Query refusing to pay attention to order clause

Tags: mysql

I am building a site that lists millions of directories and trying to build a proper search engine for the front end users. I am using the following code currently:

```
(SELECT * 
     FROM directories 
     WHERE title LIKE '%directory%' 
         AND title LIKE '%submit%' 
         AND nofollow='0' 
         AND pr_page >= '2' 
     ORDER BY pr_page DESC) 
UNION 
(SELECT * 
     FROM directories 
     WHERE title LIKE '%directory%' 
         OR title LIKE '%submit%' 
         AND nofollow='0' 
         AND pr_page >= '2' 
     ORDER BY pr_page DESC)
```

The main problem is the ordering, it does not seem to even pay any attention to the order clauses at all.

Comment: Not really answering the question, I think you are missing some parenthesis for the `OR` section in the second query. Probably you meant `... WHERE (title LIKE '%directory%' OR title LIKE '%submit%') AND nofollow='0' ... `

Comment: In the second query, you need parens around the OR go get the order of precedence right: `...WHERE (title LIKE '%directory%' 
         OR title LIKE '%submit%')...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try creating one order by clause, which is outside of the last union.

```
(SELECT * FROM directories WHERE title LIKE '%directory%' AND title LIKE '%submit%' AND nofollow='0' AND pr_page >= '2') 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM directories WHERE title LIKE '%directory%' OR title LIKE '%submit%' AND nofollow='0' AND pr_page >= '2')
ORDER BY pr_page DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this even executes. I had no idea you could order by individual clauses in a UNION. (afaik it's not possible in SQL Server).

To resolve your problem, move the ORDER BY outside of the UNION.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    directories 
WHERE   title LIKE '%directory%' 
        AND title LIKE '%submit%' 
        AND nofollow='0' 
        AND pr_page >= '2' 
UNION 
SELECT  * 
FROM    directories 
WHERE   title LIKE '%directory%' 
        OR title LIKE '%submit%' 
        AND nofollow='0' 
        AND pr_page >= '2' 
ORDER BY pr_page DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

As there seem to be more answers to the question, here is my take:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM directories WHERE title LIKE '%directory%' AND title LIKE '%submit%' AND nofollow='0' AND pr_page >= '2' ORDER BY pr_page DESC) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT * FROM directories WHERE title LIKE '%directory%' OR title LIKE '%submit%' AND nofollow='0' AND pr_page >= '2' ORDER BY pr_page DESC)
) AS myunion
ORDER BY myunion.pr_page
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have sorted it.

Comment: @Jaime, if this works, so should Shan's answer. As he posted minutes before this answer was posted, the accepted answer *should* go to him.

Comment: Lieven, good point, as this one was higher up I assumed it was the first one. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

When you use UNION orderby is not working as usual, replace it with

```
SELECT * FROM (your query goes here)

ORDER BY X
```

where X is your order by column number